# Proper use of 'Mixins' in LESS

Tags: css, less, mixins

I am trying to create simple 'templates' using less but I imagine I might be doing so incorrectly..

here is what I am going for:

```
<div class='box'>content</div>
```

and the .less file:

```
//this is the mixin

.blueBoxNotificationDiv {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    background: #EBEBEB;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 21px;
}
```

now let's say I want to apply this 'mixin' to the div '.box'.
this is how I would have it written in the .less:

```
.box {
    .blueBoxNotificationDiv;
}
```

What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: That looks correct to me. Does what you have so far not work or something? Have you tried using the mixin with the syntax you posted?

Comment: Correct.. the mixin does not apply anything to the div.

Comment: Make sure the mixin class is above the `.box` declaration in your LESS. Also, have a look in Chrome's inspector/Firebug and see if any styles are being overridden.

Comment: Inspector shows no styles being applied at all :/

Comment: In that case, try putting the rules inside `.box` (i.e. don't use a mixin) to make sure you can apply styles in some capacity. Are you using LESS.js, or the PHP port of LESS?

Comment: Hmm I stopped using the mixin and added the styling straight to the .box, however even those are not being applied.

Comment: If there is a way to do so, check that your LESS file is first loaded, and then check it's actually compiled by LESS.js (assuming client side). You might also want to try reloading the cache with Ctrl+F5.

Comment: Double check the spelling and capitalization in your html file. There's a good chance you just missed a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

LESS variables if not written out properly (including the rule) will prevent anything else from being read in your less file.

Example of the problem:

```
@color1: #000000;
@color2: #ffffff;
@color3: ##e6e6e6;

.container {
    color:@color1;
}

.....etc
```

This should be pretty obvious but small errors can be easy to miss.. the variable '@color3' has two hashs '##'. This will break the less EVEN if you do not call the variable and none of the following code will be read (near as I can tell). Problem solved!

Comment: Can you give an example of this from the code in your OP? I'm interested to know what exactly caused the problem.

Comment: I didn't include all of my code in my OP, take a look at my edited answer above. It was a small mistake, but clear to cause a problem! Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: I've often wondered why half the styles on my page break, then I find a missing semi-colon and it all works again! There should be an easier way to validate CSS (the W3C validator is a bit difficult to do quickly), or even a LESS validator.

Comment: @Bojangles I know this is an old comment of yours, but Codekit will notify you of errors and what lines they're on every time you save the file. http://incident57.com/codekit/?codekitCB=402602985.241876

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Codekit looks pretty useful. If they ever release it for Windows I'll give it a try. I'm using Grunt with LESS now, and that gives good error messages so I found a solution